# Is it possible to call a codeigniter library inside another library file?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to call a function in a library inside another library which is written by me. Is it possible to do this in codeigniter? If so, can anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could do;

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->library('your_library');
$CI->your_library->do_something();
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to access a member method from another member, ie a library method from another library, this worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: also if you want to load the parent library into a controller u must explicitly load the child class into the controller also , or u will get "A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: [controller name]::$[called method of child library]"

Answer (score 17):

Typically, you reference the Codeigniter object (the current controller, technically) by using `get_instance()`. Often you'll want to assign it to a property of your library, like this:

```
class My_Library {

    private $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        // Assign by reference with "&" so we don't create a copy
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
    }

    function do()
    {
        $var = $this->CI->my_other_library->get();
        // etc. 
    }
}
```

Just make sure the other library is loaded or in your `config/autoload.php`.